# How to make a non responsive site by using Bootstrap?

Tags: css

i want to make a non responsive site.But since i am using BS2 it's not become pure non responsive. how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just need to use the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) (not the fluid one), and don't add the bootstrap-responsive.css file to your site.

As a side note, you don't even need to use a fixed container: use a `<div class="container">` to have a 960px-wide wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You could also not include the bootstrap-responsive CSS and JS files.

Also what **simone** said above would get you started.

Answer (score 0):

For BS2, you can simply omit the responsive CSS stylesheet. But in Bootstrap 3 RC, just do not use the responsive classes and your site will be targeting desktops. Do note that with the future versions of bootstrap, there is going to be a single bootstrap stylesheet (unlike before, where we had one for desktop and other for responsiveness). So by omitting the responsive bit of the classes in your grid system implementation, you should have a non-responsive site already.